# loop counter case in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

Is there any loop counter in procedure.

How to handle below case.

```
 BEGIN
      FOR recAnnLang IN getLang(var_non_subscribe)

        LOOP

          // if loop 1 recAnnLangCode.Ann_Lang assign to var1 
          var1 := recAnnLangCode.Ann_Lang;
         // if loop 2 recAnnLangCode.Ann_Lang assign to var2 
          var2 := recAnnLangCode.Ann_Lang;
          // if loop 3 recAnnLangCode.Ann_Lang assign to var2 
          var3 := recAnnLangCode.Ann_Lang;

        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
         dbms_output.put_line('Debug :: Inside Exception because data not found ' ); 
    END;
```

Comment: Declare a local variable for this block, possibly `number`, `int` or `pls_integer`. initialize it's value with 0 before entering the loop, increment it by `1` right when you enter the loop and add an `IF` verification before each variable assignment, where you check if this variable is equal to `1` or `2` or `3` and if conditions are `TRUE` then do the logic that you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE n_counter NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    n_counter := n_counter + 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n_counter);
    IF n_counter = 5 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I did it like this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for something like

```
declare
  type a_type is table of recAnnLang.Ann_Lang%type index by pls_integer;
  val a_type;
begin
  for recAnnLang in getLang(var_non_subscribe) loop
    val(nvl(val.last, 0) + 1) := recAnnLang.Ann_Lang;
  end loop;

  for i in 1 .. val.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(val(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe,if getlang is an explicit cursor,you may think of using rownum in the cursor query select clause and use it as the counter.